# Php _GET Method as Prepared Statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am attempting to patch all of the SQL Injection vulnerabilities on a existing website.

One of my php files uses the _GET method inside of the ternary operator.

details.php:

```
<?php
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']=".";
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/include/CHtml.php');
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/include/CExtra.php');
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/include/CDetailMenu.php');
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/include/CDetail.php');
//include 'ChromePhp.php';

// Get Html Page Header
GetPageHeader();
GetTopMenu();

// Get Html Page Body
$menu_js = '';
$img_pd_header = '';

$did = (isset($_GET['did'])) ? $_GET['did'] : 0 ;
$mid = (isset($_GET['mid'])) ? $_GET['mid'] : 0 ;

$menu_html = (isset($_GET['gid'])) ? GetDetailMenu($_GET['gid']) : GetDetailMenu($_GET['mid']);
$detail_html = GetDetailContent($_GET['mid'], $did);

GetPageBody($menu_html, $detail_html);

if ($mid == 10) 
    $menu_js .= '
        $(\'#gallery a\').lightBox();
';

// Get Html Page Footer
GetPageFooter(false, $menu_js);

?>
```

This value is passed along to a function in another php file to be used in constructing a SQL statement.

detailmenu.php:

```
<?php
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/include/CDataSet.php');
include 'config.php';
//include 'ChromePhp.php';

function GetDetailMenu($gid) {
    global $menu_js;
    global $DB;

    $dbh= new mysqli($DB->host,$DB->user,$DB->pass,$DB->database);
    if ($dbh->connect_errno) {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $dbh->connect_errno . ") " . $dbh->connect_error;
    }

    $cid = 0;
    $dataset = new CDataSet();

    if ($gid > 0) {
        //$sql = 'SELECT PID FROM menu WHERE MID = '.$gid;      // Old SQL Statement
        // Prepared statement, stage 1: prepare 
        if (!($sqlstmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT PID FROM menu WHERE MID = ?"))) {
                echo "Prepare failed: (" . $dbh->errno . ") " . $dbh->error;
        }

        /* Prepared statement, stage 2: bind and execute */
        if (!$sqlstmt->bind_param('i',$gid)) {
                echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $sqlstmt->errno . ") " . $sqlstmt->error;
        }

        if (!$sqlstmt->execute()) {
                echo "Execute failed: (" . $sqlstmt->errno . ") " . $sqlstmt->error;
        }

        $ds = $dataset->GetFirstRecord($sql);
        $cid = $ds['PID'];
    }

    $sql = 'SELECT FST_ID, '.GetFieldName('FST_NAME').', SND_ID, '.GetFieldName('SND_NAME').', TRD_ID, '.GetFieldName('TRD_NAME').', IMG_FILE, IS_PRODUCT, '.
        'SND_FILE, SND_FILENAME, TRD_FILE, TRD_FILENAME '.
        'FROM view_menu';

    $dlmenu = $dataset->GetDataSet($sql);
    $dataset = null;

    $menu_html = '
<div style="float: left; padding-left: 22px;" id="my_menu" class="sdmenu">';
    $mid = 0;
    $idx = 0;
    foreach($dlmenu as $key=>$value) {
        if (!($value['IS_PRODUCT'])) {
            if ($mid <> $value['FST_ID']) {
                if ($mid > 0) $menu_html .= '
    </div>';
                $menu_html .= '
    <div class="collapsed">
    <span>'.stripslashes($value['FST_NAME']).'</span>';
                $mid = $value['FST_ID'];
                if ($mid == $cid) {
                    $img_pd_header = $value['IMG_FILE'];
                    $menu_js = '
        var expendMenu = myMenu.submenus['.$idx.'];
        myMenu.expandMenu(expendMenu);      // Expand a submenu
';
                }
                ++$idx;
            }
            if ($value['TRD_ID'] == '') {
                if ($value['SND_FILE'])
                    $menu_html .= '
        <a href="images/menu/'.urldecode($value['SND_FILENAME']).'" target="_doc">&nbsp;<img src="./images/dot.gif">&nbsp;&nbsp;'.stripslashes($value['SND_NAME']).'</a>';
                else
                    $menu_html .= '
        <a href="'.parse_url_query('detail.php?mid='.$value['SND_ID']).'">&nbsp;<img src="./images/dot.gif">&nbsp;&nbsp;'.stripslashes($value['SND_NAME']).'</a>';
            } else {
                if ($value['TRD_FILE'])
                    $menu_html .= '
        <a href="images/menu/'.urldecode($value['TRD_FILENAME']).'" target="_doc">&nbsp;<img src="./images/dot.gif">&nbsp;&nbsp;>&nbsp;&nbsp;'.stripslashes($value['TRD_NAME']).'</a>';
                else
                    $menu_html .= '
        <a href="'.parse_url_query('detail.php?mid='.$value['TRD_ID'].'&gid='.$value['SND_ID']).'">&nbsp;<img src="./images/dot.gif">&nbsp;&nbsp;>&nbsp;&nbsp;'.stripslashes($value['TRD_NAME']).'</a>';
            }
        }
    }
    $menu_html .= '
    </div>
</div>';
    return Chinese_TradToSimp($menu_html);
}
?>
```

I can create a prepared statement and verify the results under detailmenu.php, but I do not know how to create a prepared statement for just the _GET command. Examples I've seen show it being initiated in the bind_params() function, but I do not have an associated statement to bind to. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

To add, Ive also tried using the real_escape_string() function to no success.

```
if (isset($_GET['mid']))
    $mid = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbh, $_GET['mid']);
else
    $mid = 0;
```

The SQL Injection makes it in every time :(

Comment: If you're using prepared statements there's rarely a reason to manually escape things. It's not clear what you mean here with "just for the _GET command". You've got a statement there that looks good. What's the problem with using it? Normally you just call `bind_param` with your `$_GET` variable as the value being bound.

Comment: Where is the `GET` being used in the SQL?

Comment: Remember when using a ternary the best plan is to keep the duplication to a minimum: `GetDetailMenu($_GET[isset($_GET['gid']) ? 'gid' : 'mid'])` is a lot more compact and should do the trick. You can also sometimes get away with `GetDetailMenu($_GET['gid'] || $_GET['mid'])` if those values are both logically true when set.

Comment: @chris85 The original statement was as follows: $sql = 'SELECT PID FROM menu WHERE MID = '.$gid;

Comment: Okay, then in that case replace `$gid` with a placeholder, and then bind the parameter. What you have started with, `$dbh->prepare("SELECT PID FROM menu WHERE MID = ?"` looks correct. Do you later bind that or is that all you have?

Comment: @chris85 `/* Prepared statement, stage 2: bind and execute */
     if (!$sqlstmt->bind_param('i',$gid)) {
        echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $sqlstmt->errno . ") " . $sqlstmt->error;
     }` This is my binding statement, I believe it is correct because the functionality of the page remains the same. However, the SQL Injection is executed before the variable is passed along to this function. Please see @Plenka's response below for more detail.

Comment: Can you update the `detailmenu.php` in the question to include your full SQL interaction?

Comment: @chris85 Full code has been uploaded, I believe only the section in the `if($gid > 0)` is relevant in detailsmenu.php. Also, SQL injection takes place in details.php

Comment: Show `details.php` in that case..

Comment: @chris85 Added details.php

Answer (score -2):

Probably the easiest and least intrusive way *in this case* is casting the IDs to integers (the code does the same, but is a bit more readable in my opinion):

```
<?php
$id = (isset($_GET['gid'])) ? intval($_GET['gid']) : 0 ;
if ($id == 0 && isset($_GET['mid'])) {
    $id = intval($_GET['mid']);
}

$menu_html = GetDetailMenu($id);
```

Is it the best solution? Absolutely not, but it will get the job done.

Comment: Casting does not appear to work. I get the correct parameter for the GetDetailMenu() function, however SQL injection has already occurred by that point. I believe it maybe being executed in the `isset($_GET['mid])` in the if statement.

Comment: That's not possible. SQL injection is by definition only possible in SQL queries. The only explanation I can think of is that the GET parameter is also used elsewhere.

Comment: @steffensq what is the SQL injection you are getting? Updating data, exposing credentials, deleting data, etc.

Comment: @chris85 Exposing credentials.